# is there anyway to avoid dependency array in react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a functional component lets say Offers.This component on load calls an api say `api_1`. once the response of `api_1` is received and is success I want to trigger another api call say `api_2` and based on the response of `api_2` want to show `success screen` else `error screen`. Also, in case `api_1` fails i want to show `error screen`

```
const Offers =()=>{

const[api_1Success,setApi_1Success]=useState(null);
const[api_1Failure,setApi_1Failure]=useState(null);
const[api_1FetchComplete,setApi_1FetchComplete]=useState(null);

const[api_2Success,setApi_2Success]=useState(null);
const[api_2Failure,setApi_2Failure]=useState(null);
const[api_2FetchComplete,setApi_2FetchComplete]=useState(null);

const showSuccess =useCallback(() =>{
//sets some other state to render success page
},[api_2Success]);

const showError =useCallback(() =>{
//sets some other state to render error page
},[]);

const changeScreen = useCallback(() => {
  if(api_2Success){
    showSuccess();
  } else {
    showErrorScreen();
  }

},[api_2Success,showSuccess,showErrorScreen]);

useEffect(()=>{  /** first useEffect **/
//dummy api call
dummyApiCall().then((response)=>{
setApi_1Success(response);
}).catch(ex=>(setApi_1Failure(ex))).finally(()=>(setApi_1FetchComplete(true)));
},[])

useEffect(()=>{   /** second useEffect **/
if(api_1FetchComplete){
  if(api_1Success){
    //dummy api call
    dummyApiCall().then((response)=>{
    setApi_2Success(response);
  }).catch(ex=>(setApi_2Failure(ex))).finally(()=>(setApi_2FetchComplete(true)));
 }
}
if(api_1Failure){
changeScreen();
}
},[
api_1FetchComplete,
api_1Failure,
api_1Success,
changeScreen,
])

useEffect(()=>{ /** third useEffect **/
if(api_2FetchComplete){
  changeScreen();
}

},[api_2FetchComplete,changeScreen]);

return(....);
}
```

Now whenever response of `api_2` is available 3rd useeffect runs as a result the changeScreen method changes as it is dependent on `api_2success`.Now since changeScreen has changed 2nd useEffect gets called and the loop continues.

Is there any why i can avoid adding changeScreen in the dependency Array

Answer (score 1):

Creating an `async/await` function could help to create and understand the asynchronous flow better:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const getResponses = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await dummyApiCall();
        setApi_1Success(response);

        const response2 = await dummyApiCall();
        setApi_2Success(response2);
      } catch (error) {
        changeScreen();
      }
    };

    getResponses();
  }, []);
```